# NavGraph with dynamic destinations - restore after process kill

Tags: android, androidx, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

This is the setup:

- View-based Android UI
- Using androidx.navigation library (tested with versions 2.4.1 and 2.5.0-beta01)
- Activity, consisting of a bottom bar and a `NavHostFragment`

What's special is that the navigation structure is defined by the server. The top-level destinations are available during `Activity.onCreate()`. Other detail screens (=children of the top-level destinations) are only known when performing more server calls while navigating down in the hierarchy.

This is an excerpt of the body of `Activity.onCreate()`:

```kotlin
val navController = findNavController(R.id.navigationHostFragment)

val topLevelDestinations = getTopLevelDestinations()

// some additional destinations are defined statically in navigation.xml (e.g. settings)
val staticNavGraph = navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.navigation)

graph = staticNavGraph.apply {
    setStartDestination(topLevelDestinations.first())
    addDynamicDestinations(staticNavGraph, topLevelDestinations)
}
```

This code works initially. The `NavGraph` contains the top-level destinations.

Some top-level destinations offer navigation to children elements. These destinations are added to the `NavGraph` in a just-in-time manner, i.e. just before `navigate()` is called.

When the user navigated to a detail screen, the app process is killed and the app is re-opened, then `onCreate()` is called again and the app crashes during `setGraph()`/`graph =` with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Restoring the Navigation back stack failed: destination -1178236840 cannot be found from the current destination Destination(0x1a356ec2) ...
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.kt:1128)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1086)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:100)
```

To solve this I'd be fine with either of these options:

1. Find a way, the entire `NavGraph` is saved persistently and restored
2. Prevent `NavController` from trying to recover the last destination, but show the initial start destination again.

Regarding 2. I tried calling `navController.popBackStack(startDestination, false)` and `navController.clearBackStack(startDestination)` before `setGraph()` is called but this doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: Did you solve issue?

Comment: No. I worked around it by wrapping the graph creation code with try-catch and catch the `IllegalStateException`. In the catch block, I finish and recreate the Activity.